# If condition is true run some include yml files

Tags: ansible

I have some playbook for `ubuntu` and `centos` and I want to use `main.yml` to check `when: ansible_os_family == 'RedHat' or ansible_distribution == 'Centos'`, run playbooks ( as some ans many :-)  ).

When I run just:

```
-include: centos-xxx.yml
-include: centos-xaa.yml
-include: centos-xsss.yml
```

It will run all of them

Basically I want that the playbook will run if meet condition.

I didn't find any doc that say how to run include: more then one i am trying to not make task per include if possible.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use the [when conditional](https://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_conditionals.html#applying-when-to-roles-and-includes) to include files. This is somewhat common, in fact.

```
- include: centos-xxx.yml
  when: ansible_os_family == 'RedHat' or ansible_distribution == 'Centos'
- include: debian-xxx.yml
  when: ansible_distribution == 'Debian'
```

Per your comment- if you want to run them in order, you have two options. Here's the straightforward:

```
- include: centos-a.yml
  when: ansible_os_family == 'RedHat' or ansible_distribution == 'Centos'
- include: centos-b.yml
  when: ansible_os_family == 'RedHat' or ansible_distribution == 'Centos'
- include: centos-c.yml
  when: ansible_os_family == 'RedHat' or ansible_distribution == 'Centos'
- include: centos-d.yml
  when: ansible_os_family == 'RedHat' or ansible_distribution == 'Centos'
```

Or, you can do this:

```
- include: centos.yml
  when: ansible_os_family == 'RedHat' or ansible_distribution == 'Centos'
```

and inside `centos.yml`:

```
- include: centos-a.yml
- include: centos-b.yml
- include: centos-c.yml
- include: centos-d.yml
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer but my intention is like this 
  - name: check if centos
    - include: Centos-A.yml
    - include: Centos-b.yml
    - include: Centos-c.yml
    - include: Centos-d.yml
    - include: Centos-e.yml
      when: ansible_os_family == 'RedHat' or ansible_distribution == 'Centos'

i want that all of this include will run in order A to E

Comment: I added some examples that may cover that, @NoamGreenberg.

Comment: hi did you try it ? 
the include is skipping the "when"

Comment: It seems you can no longer do this in Ansible 2.0? - https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-core/issues/2298 - any alternative?

Comment: One issue at least with 1.9.4 is that the file and module are included even if condition fails. So if issue is with importing for example `yum` module but machine does not have yum installed, then it fails anyway.

Comment: NOTE: All the includes above will be included. The mechanism above is appending the `when: ...` to every task within each of the `include:...` lines.